# NancyFx self hosted with Razor View engine - Intellisense errors

Tags: razor, nancy

I've written a NancyFx web app which is self (Nancy) hosted using it's Razor view engine.  Everything works great, however I'm getting Intellisense errors in Visual Studio complaining about the "dynamic" keyword within the view and missing references for the view file:

[image]

I thought I followed the directions at [Razor View Engine](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine) but maybe the self-hosted configuration is causing issues?  Also, I'm using ReSharper so maybe Resharper is showing these phantom errors?  Again, the project compiles and executes flawlessly.

Comment: Did you manage to get to the bottom of this issue? I have the same intellisense errors and my app.config is full of assembly references in an attemt to get rid of these annoying errors.